# Standard App Engine migrating to Go 1.11 cloud build failed

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-build

I am trying to migrate from Go 1.9 to Go 1.11. I am using cloudbuild.yaml to get dependencies and deploy the application. However, I am getting this error:

```
Failed to build app: Your app is not on your GOPATH, please move it there and try again.
```

I checked [the migration document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences#package-main), and it says I need to put the application into the GOPATH. However, I am not sure if that's possible with cloudbuild.yaml. If yes, could someone share an example?

A simplified version of my cloudbuild.yaml. As far as I know the application source code is under /workspace in this situation. I have tried to include /workspace in GOPATH in the deploy step but no luck.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/go'
  args: ['get', 'github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql']
  env: ['GOPATH=go']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', 'go/src/batch.yaml']
  env: ['GOPATH=go']
```

File structure:

```
/repo
  |-go
     |-src
        |-batch.yaml
        |cronjob.go
```

Comment: It turns out this is because the folder structure hasn't been updated as the migration document requires. Moving the go script and yaml into a folder resolved the issue, it seems